# Google rel="next/prev" for dynamic pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, google-search-console

I'm trying to add this rel="next" and rel="prev" to my pagination links, but they appear to be dynamically created. I don't the coding enough to tweak it.

```
<? for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageNumber; $i++): ?>
  <? if ($i != $curPageIndex+1): ?><a href="<?= $base_url.'/'.$i.$suffix ?>"><? endif ?>
  <?= $i ?>
  <? if ($i != $curPageIndex+1): ?></a><? endif ?>
<? endfor ?>
```

Where can I put the rel="next" / rel="prev" part. It seems like I can only add one or the other, unless I would have to create another if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added a javascript tag, but posted PHP code. Assuming you want to write PHP code:

Yes, you add additional IFs to determine which (if any) rel attribute you need to output.

```
<? 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageNumber; $i++){
        // determine relative flag
        $relAttr = "";
        // this pageNr is one below the current page
        if( $i == $curPageIndex ){ $relAttr = ' rel="prev"'; } 

        // this pageNr is one above the current page
        if( $i == $curPageIndex+2 ){ $relAttr = ' rel="next"'; }


        if ($i != $curPageIndex+1){
            // this is not the current page, make a link with rel attribute
            echo '<a href="'.$base_url.'/'.$i.$suffix.'" '.$relAttr.'><'.$i.'</a>';
        }else{
            // this is the current page, only output page number
            echo $i;
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Whoops! You're right. I meant to say PHP. Thanks for noticing and adjusting the code for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note: Although "rel" attributes on links are technically OK, Google supports rel next/prev only on link elements in the html head.

The reason for this is that the document body may contain user generated content, so using information from the body is less secure (as rel=next/prev may have implications on web search rankings, this is a thing)

See:

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744

Apart from this detail, dube's answer of course is totally right :-)